We have a bad case of socks on ELL, please help
I suspect there are at least eight sockpuppets operating on ELL. I've downvoted, I've flagged, I've commented but to no avail. After 18 hours of abuse, their accounts are still working, and "earning" as much as 300 rep at a time.
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360073/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360071/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360078/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360069/1694
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360070/1694
UPDATE
Three accounts have had their reputation reduced to 1
One more to go with 74 rep
https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/360045/1694
Thank you for those who raised red flags.

Reduced to 1 due to the -100 rep for red flags

@ShadowWizard  Ahh! I forgot about the number of red flags. Good news!

Just one sock left with 74 rep user:258290
